# Multiplicacion de pares mediante una lista

Tags: haskell

tengo la tupla

```
import Data.List (partition) 

 paresImpares :: Integral a => [a] -> ([a],[a])
 paresImpares = partition even
 paresImpares = partition even*partition even
```

me devuelve

```
        paresImpares [3,2,4,5,7]
([2,4],[3,5,7])
```

pero solo quiero que me de el cuadrado de los numeros pares, sin modificar los numero impares.

```
 ([4,16],[3,5,7])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios metodos para conseguir eso, pero puede probar esto:

Primero cuadra los numeros pares.

`[3,2,4,5,7]` se convierte en `[3,4,16,5,7]`

y luego hace el partition.

`[3,4,16,5,7]` se convierte en `([4,16],[3,5,7])`

**El codigo:**

```hs
paresImpares :: Integral a => [a] -> ([a],[a])
paresImpares = partition even . map (\x -> if even x then x*x else x)
```

Usamos el funcion *map* para cuadrar los numeros pares

Answer (score 0):

La solución de @Luke es sencilla, pero chequea dos veces cada número para ver si es par. Además no es estrictamente similar al enunciado, ya que la partición de la lista se hace después de elevar al cuadrado los pares. Si fuera otro tipo de operación no serviría esta solución.

Una solución mejor es usando *Aplicativos*, que nos permite operar una vez hecha la partición:

```
paresImpares :: Integral a => [a] -> ([a],[a])
paresImpares = (,) <$> map (^2).fst <*> snd <$> partition even
```